# Debug Assertion Failed Expression: GetInterface()!=0 error when writing to database table

Tags: c++, mfc, oledb

Im working on a MFC project which communicates specific table on my SQL Server. But when I try to make delete query I get Debug Assertion Failed error message at runtime and also nothing is deleted when I check my table.
This is the code where I think the error is:

```
<pre> HRESULT hr;
    hr=COLEDBTESTSetAccessor::OpenDataSource();
    if(FAILED(hr))
        MessageBox(NULL,"Connection Failed\n","",MB_OK);
    else
        MessageBox(NULL,"Connected\n","",MB_OK);
    CString strString;
    strString.Append("DELETE FROM PHONE_NUMBERS WHERE ID=");
    CString strParam;
    strParam.Format("%d",nId);
    strString.Append(strParam);
    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCSTR)strString,"",MB_OK);
    hr=this->Open(m_session,strString); <code>
```

The same also happens with Update and Insert Query but the table records are updated. 
Can anyone tell me where is my mistake?
Thank you. :)

Comment: Very shoddy error handling.  When you get an error code that indicates failure, don't just say "It didn't work!"  Because that doesn't help anybody to figure out why it didn't work, including you.  Just continuing to execute code in spite of the failure is of course a very drastic mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see from what base class you derive you class. I assume you have a Command object.

So what happens is that you already performed an operation with an Open call. But after an open you need a Close operation before you can use the command again with a new statement and Open operation.

Look at the m_spCommand member.